# GLES in Surfaceview

Tags: java, android, 3d, gles

I am trying to implement and use GL10 in surfaceview. When i got no syntax error, nothing drew. Glsurfaceview is also according to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/refs/heads/main/opengl/java/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java extension of surfaceview to draw.

I am just trying to draw a few triangles, i googled and only got GLSURFACEVIEW or Surfaceview with canvas and GPT wrote how the google source starts but then also not work. How to make GLES10 work on just Surfaceview? I found that even android documentation says its possible with additional setup but no tutorial.